# Easiest way to join string with special handling for the last entry

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to concat a list of entries:

```
var arry = ['Jane', 'John', 'Tim'];
```

You could of course use `arry.join(', ')`, which produces:

```
'Jane, John, Tim'
```

But what if I wanted:

```
'Jane, John, and Tim'
```

I know I can iterate with a for loop and track when I'm at the last index and then use some `if` logic to handle this, but I wondered if there was a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could try to get fancy with `slice`, you end getting undesired effects (like, `"John, and Tim"` if you only have two entries).

I'd just give myself a function to do it the long way:

```
function oxfordCommaList(arry) {
    var rv;
    var last = arry[arry.length - 1];

    switch (arry.length) {
        case 0:
            rv = "";
            break;

        case 1:
            rv = last;
            break;

        case 2:
            rv = arry[0] + " and " + last;
            break;

        default:
            rv = arry.slice(0, -1).join(", ") + ", and " + last;
            break;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iVITaNA/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iVITaNA/1/edit)

Then I'd use that wherever I wanted it.

Comment: Thanks for the function name, I didn't know the term for what I was asking. Like how yours handles 2 entries as well.

Comment: @plalx: Yeah, I caught that doing the live example. Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder N.p, I also think the implementation would be prettier if you just returned from the case statements rather than using `rv`. That would remove ~10 lines of code and the `rv` variable.

Comment: @plalx: It would, but it would make it harder to debug. Having a  single return is one of the coding best practices used in highly-robust code. Any reasonable engine will in fact optimize out the `rv` variable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Really? That's the first time I hear this. I actually do this quite often, priorizing returning out of a function rather than wrapping it's whole body in a if statement for instance. Why does multiple return statements makes it harder to debug?

Comment: @plalx: You can always easily see (e.g., with a breakpoint on the `return rv`) what's going to be returned *before* it's returned. Particularly important if you have a function called as part of a complex expression, and/or if the return value is the result of a complex expression. (This is actually required in code written to certain military standards.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
arry.slice(0,-1).join(', ')+', and '+arry.slice(-1)
```

If you expect `arry` to have less than 3 elements, you should test the length :

```
arry.length<3 ? arry.join(', ') : arry.slice(0,-1).join(', ')+', and '+arry.slice(-1)
```

Comment: Produces `John, and Tim` if only given two entries. Also creates two temporary copies of the array.

Comment: I'm not sure about the rules of the English language, is ", and" normal ? if not, the last comma can be easily removed.

Comment: @dystroy: Both "A, B, and C" (called the "Oxford comma") and "A, B and C" are acceptable in English. The key is to be consistent within a given work. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've just found it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). I still find this last comma very strange...

Comment: @dystroy: And I find the absence of it very strange, when I see (or rather, don't see) it. :-) I wish I could say that the Oxford comma was right and everything else wrong and lazy, but I can't. But "John, and Tim" is never correct when you're giving a list with only two entries. (It can be correct if the "and Tim" is actually a parenthetical phrase, not part of the list.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Array.slice:

```
var a = ['Jane','John','Tim'];
a.slice(0,a.length-1).join(', ') + ', and ' + a[a.length-1]
// --> "Jane, John, and Tim"
```

Comment: OK, dystroy was faster :-)

Answer (score 0):

With angularjs it would be as easy as

```
$scope.arry = ["Jane", "John", "Tim", "Bob"];
$scope.plural = {0: 'Nobody is viewing.',
                 1: '{{person1}} is viewing.',
                 2: '{{person1}} and {{person2}} are viewing.',
                 other: '{{person1}}, {{person2}} and {} other people are viewing.'
}
```

And html:

```
<p x-count="arry" x-when="plural" x-offset="2"></p>
```

result in

```
<p x-count="arry" x-when="plural" x-offset="2">Jane, Jhon, and 2 other are viewing.</p>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: Hum... that's quite off topic.

Comment: whould have thought so, just want to show how grate angularjs is

Comment: that's fine and I like angular too, however you should post a comment rather than an answer in these cases.